# Search google drive file by name and get its ID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a file name and a specific folder ID where I will my file with its name. Finally I want to get the ID of the file by searching by name.

```
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0AIigAJ4047IdUk9PVA');
  var f_name = ref.rlink;
  var files = folder.getFiles();
```

I tried using while loop but did not succeeded here is my loop:-

```
while (files.hasNext()){
    if (files.getName === f_name)
    {
     var file = files.getId();
     break;
     }
  }
Logger.log(file)
```

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modification points:

- In this case, `files` is FileIterator.

  - There is no `files.getName`. In this case, it returns `undefined`.
  - `file.getId()` cannot be used.

#### Modified script:

```
var fileId = "";
while (files.hasNext()){
  var file = files.next();
  if (file.getName() === f_name) {
    fileId = file.getId();
    break;
  }
}
Logger.log(fileId)
```

Or, when you want to retrieve the file ID of the filename of `f_name` in the folder of `DriveApp.getFolderById('0AIigAJ4047IdUk9PVA')`, I think that you might be able to also use the following sample script.

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0AIigAJ4047IdUk9PVA');
var f_name = ref.rlink;
var files = folder.getFilesByName(f_name);
var fileId = files.hasNext() ? files.next().getId() : "";
```

- In this case, when the file of `f_name` is existing in the folder, `fileId` has the value of file ID. When the file of `f_name` is NOT existing in the folder, `fileId` has no value like `""`.

#### References:

- [getFiles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFiles())
- [FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator)

Comment: Thank you Tanaike I got the answer. Yesterday I came across your blog [link](https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/02/18/uploading-file-to-google-drive-using-html-and-google-apps-script/) . I need some help in that should I ask Another question.

Comment: @Mask Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your another question, I would like to support you. So when I could confirm your new post, I would like to think of the solution. When I could find the solution, I would like to propose the answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Tanaike I have posted a new question related to your code. Please find it here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63219127/how-to-run-a-preloader-on-google-drive-file-upload)

Comment: @Mask Thank you for your response. I saw it and noticed an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. I think that it will resolve your issue.