# how to run a preloader on google drive file upload

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have an html made using apps script. This html takes input and file upload from user.

```
<div class="inside_form file_upload">
<label>Upload Resume: </label>
<input id="file" type="file" onchange="saveFile(this)" class="custom_inputs">
</div>

<div class="input-field col s7">
<button id="btn" class="btn blue-grey darken-3 waves-effect waves-light right">Submit<i class="mdi-content-send right"></i></button>
</div>
```

On file upload I have used a function which uploads the file on google drive. I found this code on web made by `"Tanaike"`

Which goes like this:-

```
 document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',referstuff);

function saveFile(f) {
    const file = f.files[0];
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(e) { 
      const obj = {
        filename: file.name,
        mimeType: file.type,
        bytes: [...new Int8Array(e.target.result)]
      };
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => console.log(e)).saveFile(obj);
    };
    fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);   
  }

function referstuff()
{

 
 var ref = {};
 
 ref.ei = document.getElementById('ei').value;
 ref.en = document.getElementById('en').value;
 ref.emi = document.getElementById('emi').value;
 ref.mn = document.getElementById('mn').value;
 ref.doj = document.getElementById('doj').value;
 ref.pr = document.getElementById('pr').value;
 ref.nmref = document.getElementById('nmref').value;
 ref.emiref = document.getElementById('emiref').value;
 ref.mnref = document.getElementById('mnref').value;
 ref.pref = document.getElementById('pref').value;
 ref.rlink = document.getElementById('file').value;
 ref.reason = document.getElementById('reason').value;
 ref.plc = document.getElementById('plc').value;
 ref.dp = document.getElementById('dp').value;
 ref.exp = document.getElementById('exp').value;
 

      if (ref.ei == "" || ref.en== "" || ref.emi== "" || ref.mn== "" || ref.doj== "" || ref.pr== "" || ref.nmref== "" || ref.emiref== "" || ref.mnref== "" || ref.pref== "" || ref.plc== "" || ref.dp== "" || ref.exp== "") 
      {
           alert("You have missed to fill a mandatory field!!");
 
      } 
 
      else
      {
           if(confirm("Do you really want to submit?"))
           {
               google.script.run.refsubmission(ref);
               const elem = document.getElementById('modal1');
               const instance = M.Modal.init(elem, {dismissible: false});
               instance.open();                               
           }
           
           else
           {
               alert("Action Dismissed!")
           
           }
      }
}
```

server side code

```
function saveFile(e) {
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(e.bytes, e.mimeType, e.filename);
  DriveApp.getFolderById('0AIigAJ4047IdUk9PVA').createFile(blob);
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(e.filename).next().getId();
  
 Logger.log(file);
  
}
```

Now the issue is sometimes the file takes times to upload and the user can fire the submit button before the file uploads.

I want to block display once the file start loading and stop when its done.

Comment: You can toggle visibility of an element with `display:none` and `display:block`. So you should hide it at start an make it visible when `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler` fires.

Comment: I tried using some code but I failed where exactly can I make changes. if you can give a little more brief or put it in the answer would be of great help.

Comment: Because the code you give us is incomplete: google + referstuff is not defined, I can't testing it completly.

Comment: ok if I post the code it will be too long any ways ok I will edit my question. Done edited my question.

Comment: Sometimes if I have too long code, I post here the main parts and make a link to a jsfiddle.net example with the longer code (which is as well shortend as much as possible) for those who wants to get more information. We need the definition of `google`. You gave us only referstuff which perhaps a simple alert could emulate.

Comment: @Sascha `google` is a [built in api](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication). Agree that the code should be shortened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Disable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)  the button by default:

```
<button id="btn" class="btn blue-grey darken-3 waves-effect waves-light right" disabled>Submit<i class="mdi-content-send right"></i></button>
```

After file upload, [enable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement) it:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => {
  console.log(e);
  document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
}).saveFile(obj);
```